# How to get 64-bit addressing, full RAM access using OpenCL with 2019 MacBook Pro 16" Intel/AMD

Tags: macos, gpu, opencl, amd-gpu

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro 16".  It has an Intel Core i9, 8-core processor and an AMD Radeon Pro 5500M with 8 GB GPU RAM.

I have the laptop dual booting Mac OS 12.4 and Windows 11.

- Running `clinfo` under Windows tells me essentially that the OpenCL support is version 2.0, and that the addressing is 64-bits, and the max allocatable memory is between 7-8 GB.
- Running `clinfo` under Mac OS tells me that OpenCL support is version 1.2, that addressing is 32-bits little endian, and the max allocatable memory is about 2 GB.

I am guessing this means that any OpenCL code I run is then restricted to using 2GB because of the 32-bit addressing (I thought that limit was 4GB), but I am wondering a) is this true and b) if it is true, is there any way to enable OpenCL under Mac to use the full amount of GPU memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCL support on macOS is not great and has not been updated/improved for almost a decade. It always maxes out at version 1.2 regardless of hardware.

I'm not sure how clinfo determines "max allocatable memory," but if this refers to `CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE`, this is not necessarily a hard limit and can be overly conservative at times. 32-bit addressing may introduce a hard limit though. I'd also experiment with allocating your memory as multiple buffers rather than one giant one.

For serious GPU programming on macOS, it's hard to recommend OpenCL these days - tooling and feature support on Apple's own Metal API is much better, but of course not source compatible with OpenCL and only available on Apple's own platforms. (OpenCL is now also explicitly deprecated on macOS.)

Comment: this is the conclusion I am coming to.  In the course of my searching, I found the pocl project.  I am trying to compile it to see if it enables more support than Apple's implementation, but haven't been successful yet.  I will report back once I figure that out.

Comment: I don’t know if pocl has a Metal backend, but if it does, that sounds like an excellent solution.

Comment: As of right now I don't think anything has a Metal backend yet. One can hope

Comment: pocl doesn't support AMD.  I did get it to build but I did not even get it to recognize my CPU :-(.  I'm going to let this sit for a little but after some more research if its a deadend this will be the accepted answer